# Background Worker ReportProgress method

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

The `ReportProgress` method takes in 2 parameters. One's an int and one's a user state. I am passing some string parameters into the method for some processsing purposes and have no need for the int.

Is there a way to omit passing the first int without having the redundancy to call the report progress method with a `ReportProgress([randomInt], "MyString")`? Just for code cleaning purposes.

Comment: Nope, just pass 0. Or a const called `dummyProgress` if you prefer. :)

Comment: Is there a way to maybe create like an override method? This "useless parameter" thing is bugging me a little =)

Comment: Haha ok give me a sec. :)

Comment: Ok I wrote an override method for you to use as an extension method (I guess that's what you meant by an override method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an extension method for BackgroundWorker like so:

```
public static class BackgroundWorkerExt
{
    public static void ReportProgress(this BackgroundWorker self, object state)
    {
        const int DUMMY_PROGRESS = 0;
        self.ReportProgress(DUMMY_PROGRESS, state);
    }
}
```

Then you will be able do do the following (as long as the parameter is NOT an int, otherwise the normal `ReportProgress(int)` will be called):

```
_backgroundWorker.ReportProgress("Test");
```

Answer (score 2):

The *`ReportProgress`* method needs to take an int, since it raises the `ProgressChanged` event, which has a parameter `ProgressChangedEventArgs`, which in turn has a property `ProgressPercentage`.

Simply pass 0 to the method or, as RobSiklos suggests, write an extension method that will call `ReportProgress` with a 0.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method which hides the first parameter (just calls the real method with `0`)

Comment: How would you create an extension method?